# Redirect if nothing is select in the View's jump menu

Tags: routes, 7

In D7, I have a view that produces a jump menu. As a default label for the jump menu I display "Please select category".

At the moment if I click submit while  "Please select category" is selected, it just reloads the page. I want to be able to redirect to another page instead (only if nothing has been select in the drop down). How do I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `hook_form_alter` you override the default `$options` value used in `ctools_jump_menu` for the array key `_none` to whatever site url you want to redirect to.